# Calculator does not work correctly - problem with decimal point

Tags: javascript

I am in the early stages of building a calculator. When I press "1" or "2", it works perfectly fine (replaces the the 0 with a number); however, when I try to do like "0.01", it won't display it correctly. I was assuming that the first two `if` statements would fix the issue.

```
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons) {
  numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber)
  function showNumber() {
    if (display.textContent == 0){
        display.innerHTML = " "
    }

    if (!(numberButtons.innerHTML.includes('.') && display.innerHTML.includes('.'))){//this basically says that if it has a "." dont add "."
       display.innerHTML += numberButtons.innerHTML
    }
}    
});

<div class='calculator'>
  <div class="display">0</div>    
  <button class='number' id='one'>1</button>
  <button class='number' id="two">2</button>    
  <button class='number' id='zero'>0</button>
  <button class='number' id='decimal-point'>.</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: What is `display.innerHTML = 0 + '.' + ''` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @epascarello I deleted it, sorry it was not supposed to be there

Comment: `let numberButtons =` is useless in that code, since `forEach` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Your use of both textContent and innerHTML is confusing. You can just use textContent all the time here since you're not adding HTML code. Also, you should stick to double quotation marks `"` around attributes in HTML, and use either `'` or `"` consistently in your JavaScript. They do the same thing, and there's no reason to mix and match.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if (display.textContent == 0) {
```

Will be `true` if the `textContent` is any of the following: `'0.', '0', '', '.0', '0.0', '-0', '+0'`, and so on. This is because JavaScript first *coerces* the string value to a number.

What you probably want to check instead is *strict equality* to a *string* value: `display.textContent === '0'`. You could also check against a list, using something like `['0', ''].includes(display.textContent)`, or against a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for pattern matching: `/^0?$/.test(display.textContent)`.

See [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)
 for more details about how equality works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to check a bunch of things together which is causing you issues. Using `==` is also causing issues because it can match multiple things.

Personally your logic should be broken out to handle the decimal point separate from the numbers. Using a switch statement can help clean it up.

```js
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

function showNumber() {
  let entry = this.value;
  let currentValue = display.textContent;
  if (currentValue === '0') currentValue = '';
  switch (entry) {
    case ".":
      if (currentValue.includes(".")) { // if there, do not add another
        return;
      } else if (currentValue.length === 0) { // if new, add leading zero
        currentValue = "0.";
      } else { // just add it to the end
        currentValue += ".";
      }
      break;
    default:
      currentValue += entry;
  }
  display.textContent = currentValue;
}


document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons) {
  numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber)
});
```

```html
<div class='calculator'>
  <div class="display">0</div>
  <button class='number' id='one' value="1">1</button>
  <button class='number' id="two" value="2">2</button>
  <button class='number' id='zero' value="0">0</button>
  <button class='number' id='decimal-point' value=".">.</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to make minimal adjustments here, then I've got only three changes for you.

1. Replace your mixed usage of `innerHTML` and `innerContent` with *only* one or the other.
2. Check against the *string* `'0'` rather than the number
3. Add a condition checking for the decimal point to your first `if`

```js
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons) {
  numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber);

  function showNumber() {
    if (display.innerHTML === '0' && !numberButtons.innerHTML.includes('.')) {
      display.innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (!(numberButtons.innerHTML.includes('.') && display.innerHTML.includes('.'))) { //this basically says that if it has a "." dont add "."
      display.innerHTML += numberButtons.innerHTML;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class='calculator'>
  <div class="display">0</div>
  <button class='number' id='one'>1</button>
  <button class='number' id="two">2</button>
  <button class='number' id='zero'>0</button>
  <button class='number' id='decimal-point'>.</button>
</div>
```

I would advise you to do a little cleanup concerning quotes usage, and you may find there are better approaches to making a calculator than concatenating strings in your HTML too.

Best of luck!